# How to get boundaries of visible part of canvas on screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pixi.js

[image]

I am trying to build a game on canvas using pixi and javascript, My canvas is infinite where only a smallportion will be visible, It extends beyod the visible part, I need to find the boundary of the visible portion so that once my game character reaches the edge i need to move the canvas towards the respective direction, Iam achiving it in a hard way now by keeping track of everything,
Visible part can be any where on the canvas depending on user, I need to get the boundaries, How to achieve this, any suggestions ??? I am using PIXI. And iam sorry that i cannot paste my code here as its too complicated and I dont own it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using screen width and height, Keeping track of movement  Holding the data of whats happening, but these look like expensive operations

Comment: Can you post some code of your efforts so that someone can update their answers!

Comment: Now whats happening is i have to keep track of everything including screen resolution and every movement, My canvas can be dragged, So all these things look like an over head , i just want to know if there is a better way of doing this. Iam sorry that i cannot paste my code here .

Comment: Just curious as I never used pixi, are you creating a mask as rectangle display object of pixi? and are you using _recursivePostUpdateTransform  for drag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Used Pixi Viewport to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript so you can get the canvas location and size using:-

```
var can = getElementById("can");
var width = can.width;
var height = can.height;
var left = can.style.left;
var top = can.style.top;
```

**Note** you should set canvas id to `can` to use the above code.

Comment: there's no such method like getElementById(). try with document. getElementById()